# Jboss 'JBAS015228: Unable to load properties' on statup

Tags: java, xml, oracle, jboss

I am trying to get  form-based authentication to work in Jboss EAP 6.3 with Oracle 11g. **But login always fails no matter what the input**.

I have configured a security domain in standalone.xml:

```
        <security-domain name="employee-rooster" cache-type="default">
            <authentication>
                <login-module code="Database" flag="required">
                    <module-option name="dsJndiName" value="java:jboss/datasources/OracleDS"/>
                    <module-option name="principalsQuery" value="SELECT PASSWORD FROM USERS WHERE USERNAME = ?"/>
                    <module-option name="rolesQuery" value="SELECT R.NAME, 'Roles' FROM USERS_ROLES UR INNER JOIN ROLES R ON R.ID = UR.ROLE_ID INNER JOIN USERS U ON U.ID = UR.USER_ID WHERE U.USERNAME = ?"/>
                </login-module>
            </authentication>
            <authorization>
                <policy-module code="admin" flag="required"/>
            </authorization>
            <audit>
                <provider-module code="LogAuditProvider"/>
            </audit>
        </security-domain>
```

Configured the application web.xml:

```
<web-app>
    <security-constraint>
    <display-name>auth</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
    <web-resource-name>Secure Content</web-resource-name>
    <url-pattern>/register.do/this_is-it</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
    <role-name>admin</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>

    <login-config>
        <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
        <realm-name>employee-rooster</realm-name>
        <form-login-config>
            <form-login-page>/loginForm.jsp</form-login-page>
            <form-error-page>/loginError.jsp</form-error-page>
        </form-login-config>

    </login-config>
    <security-role>
        <role-name>admin</role-name>
    </security-role>
</web-app>
```

Configured the application jboss-web.xml:

```
<jboss-web>
    <security-domain>employee-rooster</security-domain>
    <use-jboss-authorization>true</use-jboss-authorization>
</jboss-web>
```

And added some values to my tables in import.sql:

```
CREATE TABLE USERS (ID INT, USERNAME VARCHAR(32), PASSWORD VARCHAR(32));
CREATE TABLE ROLES (ID INT, NAME VARCHAR(20));
CREATE TABLE USERS_ROLES (USER_ID INT, ROLE_ID INT);

INSERT INTO USERS (ID, USERNAME, PASSWORD) VALUES (1, 'admin', 'admin');
INSERT INTO ROLES (ID, NAME) VALUES (1, 'admin');
INSERT INTO USERS_ROLES (USER_ID, ROLE_ID) VALUES (1,1);

INSERT INTO USERS (ID, USERNAME, PASSWORD) VALUES (2, 'guest', 'guest');
INSERT INTO ROLES (ID, NAME) VALUES (2, 'guest');
INSERT INTO USERS_ROLES (USER_ID, ROLE_ID) VALUES (2,2);
```

But when I deploy the app I get this error:

```
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.server.controll
er.management.security_realm.employee-rooster.properties_authentication: org.jbo
ss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.server.controller.management.secu
rity_realm.employee-rooster.properties_authentication: JBAS015228: Unable to loa
d properties
```

Login always fails, I suspect this is why.
What causes this error?

Comment: Try adding TRACE logging to JBoss Security as mentioned here https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/SecurityFAQ

Comment: Are you sure the correct standalone.xml file is used when you start JBoss? Try using ./standalone.sh --server-config=standalone-full.xml &

Comment: @ozOli I am on windows, what should I do?

Comment: @ozOli that tutorial seems to be for old versions because I don't have the files or folders mentioned there.

Comment: where is it `policy-module code="admin"`? Have you other errors in the log?

Comment: @FedericoSierra I removed the policy-module part (forgot I added it when hacking around). No other errors.

Comment: Also I removed a security realm called "employee rooster" and the error was gone, but the login still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `standalone.xml`, under `<security-realms>` I had this:

```
    <security-realm name="employee-rooster">
        <authentication>
            <properties path="employee-rooster.properties"/>
        </authentication>
    </security-realm>
```

I removed the part and the error was gone. Embarrassing, but I just forgot that piece of code.